# Ansible `archive` module to archive without compression

Tags: ansible

I have to archive a bunch of files, and want to avoid compression to save time. This is a daily operation to archive 1 TB of data, and write it to a different drive, so "time is of the essence".
Looking at the [Ansible archive module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/archive_module.html) it's not clear how to build up the target file without compression.
Currently, my Ansible task looks like this:

```
- name: Create snapshot tarball
  become: true
  archive:
    path: "{{ snapshots_path.stdout_lines }}"
    dest: "{{backup_location}}{{short_date.stdout}}_snapshot.tgz"
    owner: "{{backup_user}}"
    group: "{{backup_group}}"
```

Is it possible to speed up this process by telling the module to NOT compress? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this other answer on [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/529930/455228), `tar` is not compressing files per default, on the other hand `gz`, [which is the default `format`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/archive_module.html#parameter-format) of `archive` is.

So you could try going by:

```yaml
- name: Create snapshot tarball
  become: true
  archive:
    path: "{{ snapshots_path.stdout_lines }}"
    dest: "{{backup_location}}{{short_date.stdout}}_snapshot.tar"
    format: tar
    owner: "{{backup_user}}"
    group: "{{backup_group}}"
```

This is also backed-up by the manual page of `tar`:

> ```
> DESCRIPTION         
>       GNU tar is an archiving program designed to store multiple files in a
>       single file (an archive), and to manipulate such archives.  The
>       archive can be either a regular file or a device (e.g. a tape drive,
>       hence the name of the program, which stands for tape archiver), which
>       can be located either on the local or on a remote machine.
> ```